# Whats wrong with my mysql JOIN, I am not getting the right results

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Table A has
userIdentity (primaryKey)
userName
userPhoneNumber

Table B has
someOtherKey(primaryKey)
userIdentity
userLocation

I get 22 rows with unique userIdentity when I run

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB 
WHERE tableB.timeStamp > '2013-11-1' 
GROUP BY tableB.userIdentity ;
```

I get only 2 rows when I run (I intend to extract name and phone number of the 22 rows in the above query)

```
SELECT tableA.userName, tableA.phonePhoneNumber 
FROM tableB
JOIN tableA 
WHERE tableB.timeStamp > '2013-11-1'
GROUP BY tableB.userIdentity
    AND tableA.identityHash = tableB.identityHash;
```

Comment: You have a very funny GROUP BY there... I suspect that's your problem.  Did you put your AND clause in the wrong place?

Comment: What output do you want to show exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your 'AND' clause is in the wrong place. What you probably meant to do was:

```
SELECT tableA.userName, tableA.phonePhoneNumber 
FROM tableB JOIN tableA 
WHERE tableB.timeStamp > '2013-11-1'
    AND tableA.identityHash = tableB.identityHash
GROUP BY tableB.userIdentity;
```

Answer (score 2):

The common field between the two is `userIdentity` that should be on the `ON` clause after `JOIN` and not the `identityHash`, like:

```
 SELECT tableA.userName, tableA.phonePhoneNumber 
 FROM tableB
 JOIN tableA
 ON tableB.userIdentity = tableA.userIdentity 
 WHERE tableB.timeStamp > '2013-11-1'
 GROUP BY tableB.userIdentity
```

Check my [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90876/1)